# Navigation bar items disappear from navigation bar

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have been struggling for some time with the strange behavior of navigation bar items. I have segmented control on the navigation bar (take a look at the image below)

[image]

where **List** button pushes table view controller with UISearchDisplayController. To show table view controller I use the code as it follows:

```
if (uiSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 )
{
    DetailsTableVewController* detailsViewController = [[DetailsTableVewController alloc] 
                                                         initWithList:list]; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
    [detailsViewController release];
}
```

Then to return back I use the following code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Although I use the code above to go back to the previous controller when UISearchDisplayController is either active or inactive I have different behavior of the navigation bar items. When UISearchDisplayController is active **ALL** items disappear from the navigation bar

[image]

Does anybody know why it happens?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved all navbar initialization code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear` in controller and it solved the problem